# Instantiate doesn't work when changing GameObject within loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

I've got these two codes that do the same thing in theory but in practice behave very differently and I would like to know why/how to fix it.

```
void BlockPlacer(){ //Places breakable objects
    BlockType BlockKind = BlockType.Hard;
    GameObject Block = ReturnBlock (BlockKind);
    while(true){
        for(int j = 1; j < 4; j++){
            for(float i = -width; i < width; i++){
                GameObject created = Instantiate (Block, new Vector3 (i, height - j, 10), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
                print (created.transform.position);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

as you can see I'm instantiateing an GameObject that is created outside my two for loops and that works as you might expect, on the other example

```
void BlockPlacer(){ //Places breakable objects
    BlockType BlockKind = BlockType.Hard;
    while(true){
        for(int j = 1; j < 4; j++){
            for(float i = -width; i < width; i++){
                GameObject created = Instantiate (ReturnBlock (BlockKind), new Vector3 (i, height - j, 10), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
                print (created.transform.position);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm doing the same thing but this time I'm geting my GameObject within loops and the program only instantiates once(I've checked my code and everything is being called and returned the way I wanted it, **only instantiate doesn't behave as it should**)

My theory from testing is that the GameObject is being created at every pass of the loop, but it get's deleted an created again on the next pass, this isn't probably true, but for now, I don't have anything better. All GameObjects are being created from the same Prefab so there might be some inheritance issues. Here is the code that return my GameObject

```
GameObject ReturnBlock(BlockType Type){
    if (Type == BlockType.Soft) {
        GameObject SoftBlock = Resources.Load("GameBorderPrefab") as GameObject;
        SoftBlock.name = "SoftBlock";
        SoftBlock.tag = "Soft"; //Sets a tag for that gameobject
        SoftBlock.AddComponent<HitCounter>();
        string TextureName = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < GameManager.Bricks.Count; i++) {
            if (GameManager.Bricks [i].ID == "Soft") {
                TextureName = GameManager.Bricks [i].TextureName;
                SoftBlock.GetComponent<HitCounter> ().HP = System.Int32.Parse(GameManager.Bricks [i].HitPoints);
            }
        }
        SoftBlock.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = Resources.Load (TextureName) as Material;
        return SoftBlock;
    }if (Type == BlockType.Medium) {
        GameObject MediumBlock = Resources.Load("GameBorderPrefab") as GameObject;
        MediumBlock.name = "MediumBlock";
        MediumBlock.tag = "Medium";
        MediumBlock.AddComponent<HitCounter>();
        string TextureName = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < GameManager.Bricks.Count; i++) {
            if (GameManager.Bricks [i].ID == "Medium") {
                TextureName = GameManager.Bricks [i].TextureName;
                MediumBlock.GetComponent<HitCounter> ().HP = System.Int32.Parse(GameManager.Bricks [i].HitPoints);
            }
        }
        MediumBlock.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = Resources.Load (TextureName) as Material;
        return MediumBlock;
    }else{//if (Type == BlockType.Hard) {
        GameObject HardBlock = Resources.Load ("GameBorderPrefab") as GameObject;
        HardBlock.name = "HardBlock";
        HardBlock.tag = "Hard";
        HardBlock.AddComponent<HitCounter> ();
        string TextureName = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < GameManager.Bricks.Count; i++) {
            if (GameManager.Bricks [i].ID == "Hard") {
                TextureName = GameManager.Bricks [i].TextureName;
                HardBlock.GetComponent<HitCounter> ().HP = System.Int32.Parse (GameManager.Bricks [i].HitPoints);
            }
        }
        HardBlock.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material = Resources.Load (TextureName) as Material;
        return HardBlock;
    }
}
```

Upon further testing, I've writen this code that behaves just like the first code I presented hoping I would see three diferent lines of object being created. Only the first Instantiate worked as expected, others didn't do anything, but **all my print functions worked as you would expect**

```
BlockType BlockKind = BlockType.Hard;
    GameObject Block = ReturnBlock (BlockKind);
    int j = 1;
    for(float i = -width; i < width; i++){
        GameObject created = Instantiate (Block, new Vector3 (i, height - j, 10), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        print (created.transform.position);
    }
    j = 2;
    BlockKind = BlockType.Soft;
    Block = ReturnBlock (BlockKind);
    for(float i = -width; i < width; i++){
        GameObject created = Instantiate (Block, new Vector3 (i, height - j, 10), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        print (created.transform.position);
    }
    j = 3;
    BlockKind = BlockType.Medium;
    Block = ReturnBlock (BlockKind);
    for(float i = -width; i < width; i++){
        GameObject created = Instantiate (Block, new Vector3 (i, height - j, 10), Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0));
        print (created.transform.position);
    }
```

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please post your code as text, images don't scale properly, make it impossible to copy and test the code, and make it impossible for visually impaired people to read it.

Comment: First of all, the size of the images is too small to read easily. Second, people can't help you if you don't provide code that they can't simply copy-paste.

Comment: Removed pictures, changed it to code

Comment: The while loop is useless there so you could start removing it.

Comment: I planned to do more coding that would require it, but I'm stuck on it Everts

Comment: Is print also only called once?EDIT: nvm just saw the important sentence

Comment: everything behaves exactly the same in both codes, except the instance, in first code it will generate about 40ish objects, in other example it will only generate one

Comment: Can you post the code of the `ReturnBlock` method?

Comment: In the first code, when you use `GameObject Block = ReturnBlock (BlockKind);` It does create a gameobject for you at that point. Depending on the `ReturnBlock ()` method it may possibly just be creating an empty gameobject. And this gets repeated in the loop.
Post the `ReturnBlock ()` code if you can

Comment: Nope, at no point did my code return empty game object, also even if it did I would notice it in my inspector tab, by seeing bunch of empty game objects, right now I'm only seeing one properly instantiated GameObject

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with the `Instantiate` block. I think the `ReturnBlock` method is returning a null value.

Comment: if I write this: Block = ReturnBlock (BlockKind);
  print (Block.name); I will get names that I would expect, so what you said can't be true, also ReturnBlock is in the post so take a look

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution lies in the fact that Unity can't separate what is being instantiated and what is being kept as an empty prefab in Resources folder, that is why the instantiate function would bug out on the second call of ReturnBlock() function. I fixed my bugs by creating a new prefab from scratch for every single one of my block types, is it optimised **no**, is it a good practice **no**, but for now it get's the job done.

TL;DR Don't use one prefab to instantiate more than one object, otherwise inheritance will kick in and you will be in trouble.